# Most basic Angular app not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used yo angular to setup my project scaffolding, but changed the directory structure to be more modularized, and now I can't even get the routeProvider to work.

app.js:

```
angular
  .module('feedsmanagerApp', [
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
      debugger;
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/feedsmanager/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
  });
```

scripts/feedsmanager/home.js:

```
angular.module('feedsmanagerApp', [])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    alert('works');
});
```

index.html

```
<body ng-app="feedsmanagerApp">
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
          <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <div ng-view></div>

        <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
        <!-- bower:js -->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
        <!-- endbower -->
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/feedsmanager/home.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
```

I've put debugger statements, console.logs, anything to try to get the route "/home" to work, but all I get is a blank page and no code executions. Any ideas?

Comment: you defined your 'feedsmanagerApp' module twice.

Comment: As @Claies said, change angular.module('feedsmanagerApp', []) -> angular.module('feedsmanagerApp') in home.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are redefining the module in home.js not utilizing it

edit

```
angular.module('feedsmanagerApp', []) // declare
```

to

```
angular.module('feedsmanagerApp')  // consume
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

app.js:

```
angular
  .module('feedsmanagerApp', [
    'ngRoute', 'feedsmanagerAppHome'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
      debugger;
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/feedsmanager/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
  });
```

scripts/feedsmanager/home.js:

```
angular.module('feedsmanagerAppHome', [])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    alert('works');
});
```

Comment: in app.js there is a missing quote, must be `'ngRoute', 'feedsmanagerAppHome'`